# How can I store HTML in another file through Java

Tags: java, html, hyperlink

Hey Guys so what i want to do is a dialoge box appear, enter a URL and a file will then store the Hyperlinks of that URL.

I have the dialog box appearing but not really sure how to put connect it to another file and save just the hyperlinks instead of saving the entire HTML file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyCrawler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a URL");
        String address = "http://";
        URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.next();

            if (line.contains("href=\"http://")) {
                int from = line.indexOf("\"");
                int to = line.lastIndexOf("\"");
                System.out.println(line.substring(from + 1, to));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I also have another seperate file which stores the information of the URL oracle but it stores all the HTML information in a seperate file. Does anyone know how i could joint these 2 files together and only store the hyperlinks of the file?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class URLReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputfile.txt"));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                writer.write(inputLine);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put all of your logic into main. Extract it into separate methods and then make method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect an event handler to the text entry box within the GUI. Follow the [Swing Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to understand more.

For the purposes of downloading and parsing HTML, I highly recommend [JSoup](http://www.jsoup.org/) which will let you gain access to various aspects of the HTML such as links and perform your own application logic on them, such as adding them to a list then writing the list to a file.